# Compound Keys in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, key, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table where I have 2 pieces of information whose combination must always be unique.

By definition, if we look at these two columns for any given row, they are unique and should be `primary` or at least a `candidate` key, but in my case they are `primary`.

However, when I try to create the table with `Flask SQLAlchemy` I am told that I cannot create a table without a `primary key`.

How do I specify that these two compound keys should be treated as a `primary key`?

Edit:

Upon reading my question I thought it could use a bit more pratical description:

Givent table:

```
A | B
-----
5 | 1
5 | 2
5 | 3
5 | 4
5 | 5
6 | 1
```

We can se that no two combinations of A and B occurred. That is why I am trying to set A and B as a primary key instead of having something like:

```
id | A | B 
-----------
 1 | 5 | 1
 2 | 5 | 2
 3 | 5 | 3
 4 | 5 | 4
 5 | 5 | 5
 6 | 6 | 1
```

which just wastes memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question it sounds like you're not declaring any column as the primary key, however you can declare `primary_key=True` on multiple columns to create a composite primary key, from the SQLAlchemy docs: (the second code example shows this in action)

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key

This previous SO question might also help:

[How to define composite primary key in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129289/how-to-define-composite-primary-key-in-sqlalchemy)